# Gatling - run load tests in cluster / scaling out

Tags: bash, scala, load-testing, stress-testing, gatling

I need many api calls to stress test my app

was looking into Gatling - http://gatling.io/

and im pleased with the reports and results

problem is that it runs on 1 machine, i need to test this with many multiple HTTP connection from different networks

to do so i see the documentation for cluster run :
http://gatling.io/docs/1.5.6/user_documentation/cookbooks/scaling_out.html

but it doesn't provide sufficient information for this task.

I dont understand how im suppose to trigger the tests on the remote machines and know when they finish ?

did any 1 encounter with this problem and has a wiki / solution for this task ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've ended up writing a script to accomplish the task,

triggering the test on remote hosts using ssh and after that running the test locally
when the test finished locally the script assumes all hosts have finished.

In the end the script gathers logs and generates the test report.

checkout :

http://www.nimrodstech.com/gatling-cluster-load-testing/